# Powershell questions - how to make a variable of an output

Tags: powershell

Im fairly new to powershell and learning to make some scripts.
Right now im making a simple script to enable archives on mailboxes that have a full recoverable items in exchange online.

On the last step i need to have the 1: primary mailbox location (hash?) as a varbiale (as shown below in bold)

```
ExchangeGuid         : 45af8ec4-83c4--80290bdf4d
DatabaseGuid         : 9631c13e-fba8--9c6229be1
MailboxContainerGuid :
ArchiveDatabaseGuid  : 9631c13e-fba8--9c6289be1
ArchiveGuid          : 64d28cb6-559f--bc13e01e1
DisabledArchiveGuid  : 00000000-000000000000
Guid                 : 8cc5f81d--c4b81cd7e
MailboxLocations     : {1;45af8ec4--8c8b-80290cdf4d;Primary;EURP198.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM;9631ce-fba8--2fa89be1, 1;64d28cb6-666-bc1f3e01e1;MainArchive;EURP198.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM;9631c13e-f-9c622fa8e1}
```

How do i make a variable based on he **1; 45af8ec4--8c8b-80290cdf4d**

the script itself:

```
#### Connect to exchange online
Connect-ExchangeOnline

#### Set Username
$Username  = "Username@domain.com" 

#### Get the recoverable items size in GB
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $Username -FolderScope RecoverableItems | Format-List Name,FolderAndSubfolderSize

#### Enable Archive 
Enable-Mailbox -Identity $Username -archive

#### Get mailbox location
Get-Mailbox -identity $Username | Format-List *GUID,MailboxLocations

#### This should be the primairy 1: variable
$primary = ?

#### Start managed folder assistant 
start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity "$primary"
```

Comment: Use Select-Object and assign results to a variable.

Comment: @jdweng how do i specify i want the 1; primary?

Comment: $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -identity $Username;
$primary = $mailboxes.MailboxLocations[0];

Comment: Can you do `(Get-Mailbox -Identity $Username).MailboxLocations.GetType().FullName` so we can see what that property actually stores?

Comment: @Theo i get System.Collections.ArrayList   as result

Comment: Ok, so now I need to know what this arraylist contains. Can you show `(Get-Mailbox -Identity $Username).MailboxLocations[0].GetType().FullName` to see what the first object is?

Comment: That returns as: System.String

Comment: If i add the suggested $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -identity $Username; $primary = $mailboxes.MailboxLocations[0]; by Jdwengs comment. And run $primary i get the frist piece: 1;45af8ec4--8c8b-80290cdf4d;Primary;EURP198.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM;9631ce-fba8--2fa89be1 Where i only need the 45af8ec4--8c8b-80290cdf4d part. So im getting closer with both you help.